# About BEST and MAX MTU with PPPOE + PPTP

Tags: router, wan, mtu, wan-optimizer

About BEST and MAX MTU with PPPOE + PPTP in the router.

I have Has been setup WAN to PPPOE and MTU is 1492, because 1464 is maxed on my ISP. and I have connected PPTP on the same router, and MTU is 1942 max is 1372, so need I change WAN MTU to 1400?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *M* in MTU stands for *maximum* (transmission unit), so there's no "max MTU".

When determining the MTU in a tunnel you need to know the expected overheads from the wrapping protocols:

- PPPoE: 8 bytes
- IPv4: 20 bytes
- IPv6: 40 bytes
- TCP: 20 bytes
- UDP: 8 bytes
- PPTP (GRE): 40 bytes

The MTU outside the tunnel minus the summed overhead is the MTU inside the tunnel (unless the tunnel streams packets end-to-end, then the MTU depends on the tunnel parameters).

Comment: About BEST and MAX MTU with PPPOE + PPTP in the router, need I change WAN MTU to best?

Comment: Please check and correct your question which is not entirely clear and there seem to be typos.

Comment: I want to setup best and max MTU to my router WAN port settings. I use PPPoE (ISP) 1st and connect a PPTP VPN.

Comment: That totals to an overhead of 68 bytes (PPPoE+IP+GRE) and should be able to work with a 1432 byte MTU inside the tunnel for IPv4 outside or 1412 byte for IPv6 outside.

Comment: I need setup 1412 to 1412 router WAN (PPPOE settings)?

Comment: No. The WAN interface is outside the tunnel and is only affected by PPoE, so the MTU should be 1492.